# Split values from string and get the sum of these values

Tags: java, split, sum

I want to split the amount value from a string I got from txt file, the problem is the split value is string and even after parsing it to integer I can't accumulate the summation of it.
Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String file_name = "C:\\application\\TestFile2.txt";
    try {

        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<aryLines.length;i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            //////split each line to get the total amount
            String[] parts = aryLines[i].split("\\|");
            String amount = parts[5];
            System.out.println(amount);

        }

        /////count total number of lines
        System.out.println(file.readLines());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of string you are trying to parse? Can you post some samples?

Comment: int num = Integer.parseInt(amount);   
    num = num ++;
    System.out.println(num);

amount here is "25000"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing   num = num ++?

You should keep sum = 0 outside and sum += num in the loop;
Finally println(sum)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me. Can you please give an example of the String you want to split and what summation you want after splitting ?

Ok u can do something like this -

```
List<Integer> amt=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<aryLines.length;i++){
      String arr[]=aryLines[i].split("\\|");
        amt.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[5])); //assuming 6th position contains the amount.
    }

    Object amtArr[]=amt.toArray();
    int sum=0;
    for(int j=0;j<amtArr.length;j++){
        sum=sum+(Integer)amtArr[j];
    }

    System.out.println("Sum is: "+sum);
```

Comment: I have a text file contains data for customers each one in a line and data fields are separated by vertical bar "|", I have the balance of each customer and I want to sum all customers' balances so I split that file and print out the balances(amount), now i want to sum, that's it.